# Return Object from ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JS file that exposes a function as shown below (following is sample code):

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import Component from './Component';
(function() {
  if (!window || !window.someFunction) {
    window.someFunction = (selector) => {
      ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.querySelector(selector));
      return objectFromComponent; // I don't know how to do this
    }
  }
})();
```

When this function is called the component is rendered to the DOM. The Component actually generates a particular object that I would like to be returned somehow to this piece of JS code. I tried the following:

1. Storing in localStorage in Component.jsx and reading from callback in : `ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.querySelector(selector), () => {//listening for storage event});`
2. window.parent.postMessage in Component.jsx and event listener for "message" event in the function shown above.

Is there a more elegant way to do it with React itself rather than complicating the logic with localStorage and event listeners?

Comment: The only thing that the component should be returning is the JSX. What is the object it's generating that you need? This looks like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I agree with you but, it generates a token that comes back to the client-side after making some server calls. This piece of JS is integrated into other non-React web applications so I need to somehow return the object. All the component does is that it makes server calls on behalf of the user.

Comment: Why not store the token server-side so that all the apps have access to it?

Comment: Well that is true but the "Component" that I mention is the only easy way to generate this token. Its very hard to directly share it with the users.